# Rails form submit causes undefined method 'allow_forgery_protection' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to create a form that submits from 1 controller to another. When I do so, I get "undefined method 'allow_forgery_protection' for nil:NilClass". However, if I POST back to the same controller, it successfully submits.

Things to know

- My application controller has `protect_from_forgery` set. I'm not
  messing with `:before_filter` or anything in order to reduce
  possible problems.
- There is no model for either controller. Both were generated with `rails g controller <name>`
- Rails 3.2 if it makes a difference

#### app/controllers/first_controller.rb

```
def myaction
end
```

#### app/views/first/myaction.html.erb

```
<%= form_tag(url_for(:controller => 'second', :action => controller.action_name), :method => :post) do %>
  <fieldset>
    <%= label_tag(:file_dir, "File location") %>
    <%= text_field_tag :file_dir, "/var/log" %>
  </fieldset>
  <%= submit_tag "Submit" %>
<% end %>
```

#### app/controllers/second_controller.rb

```
def myaction
end
```

#### app/views/second/myaction.html.erb

```
<h1>Second#myaction</h1>
<p>Find me in app/views/second/myaction.html.erb</p>
```

#### routes.rb

```
 match 'first/:action' => 'first#:action'
 match 'second/:action' => 'second#:action'
```

It's probably my lack of understanding about the CSRF, but I don't see how simply changing `:controller => 'second'`to `:controller => 'first'` will determine whether the nearly identical controllers will work.

#### Part of the log

```
# Rendered the form
Started GET "/first/myaction" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-08-04 14:20:00 -0500
Processing by FirstController#myaction as HTML
Rendered first/myaction.html.erb within layouts/application (3.7ms)
Completed 200 OK in 142ms (Views: 141.9ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)


# Submitted the form here
Started POST "/second/myaction" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-08-04 14:22:00 -0500
Processing by SecondController#myaction as HTML
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"xyQetj0Wdks+iuOXNjrxs96TbEJOw4ktURTrraEARoU=",<everything else looks fine>}
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 0ms
NoMethodError (undefined method `allow_forgery_protection' for nil:NilClass):
```

Comment: could you post the rails log - it's not clear to me, what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: I'm trying to post a form rendered from the first controller to the second.  Updated post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a third controller to test with (via the same exact steps), and the form performed a POST properly.

During this same time, the second threw this forgery error consistently.

I deleted the second controller with `rails destroy controller second`, and recreated it with `rails g controller second`, keeping the same routes in routes.rb, and everything worked properly.

Comment: hmm, then you must have had some errors in your `SecondController`.

Comment: Possibly, but `SecondController` looked identical to `ThirdController` as far as I could tell, including the routes.